# How to move the title into the body area?

Tags: fonts, positioning, titles, tikzposter

While trying to typeset a poster where I need to comply with a certain design pattern, I tried using `tikzposter`. It has a lot of nice settings and features; however, I'd like to adjust it even more. This code works:

```
\documentclass[a2paper, 17pt]{tikzposter}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Hier steht der Titel}   \institute{Musterinstitut}
\author{Michael Mustermann}   \titlegraphic{LogoMI}
\usetheme{Autumn}

%% overwrite title macro; \MakeUppercase does not work here!
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[25mm] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} \sffamily{\MakeUppercase \bfseries \Huge \@title \par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Übergreifender BlocktitelA}{Blocktext}

\begin{columns}  % See Section 4.4
\column{0.5}  % See Section 4.4
\block{Linker Blocktitel B}{\blindtext[2]}
\column{0.5}
\block{Rechter Blocktitel C}{\blindtext[2]}
\note{Notetext}  % See Section 4.3
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

1. How can I move the title into the blue area, without enlarging the header (grey area) even further?
2. Why does the `\MakeUppercase` command not work in the `\settitle` part?

Comment: Use `\uppercase` instead of `\MakeUppercase` and put them in correct order. What works for me is `\sffamily{\bfseries \Huge \uppercase \@title \par}`.

Comment: Not working here! I get:
`! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
\let
l.26
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing \`I}' now.)`

Comment: Some times it is easier to NOT use \maketitle.

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` can't be used like that because it's a latex command and thus _needs to be passed an argument_. In other words you can do `\MakeUppercase{Some text goes here}` but not `\MakeUppercase \bfseries Some text goes here`. So what might work is `\MakeUppercase{\bfseries \Huge \@title}\par`. But it might not, uppercasing is a surprising pain in latex.

Comment: Even this `\MakeUppercase{\bfseries \Huge \@title}\par` doesn't work! And if I omit `\maketitle`, @John Kormylo, I get a completely blue poster with a way too big header, which is not what I want either.
So in the end, it seems `tikzposter` is not the right approach for my project. Any alternative solutions? It should support paper formats between A4 and A0.